# Logarithmic Equations: Solving for the unknown variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

What is $y$ in
$$3^{2y}\cdot3^{\log_{3}(1/3)}=9$$

I apologize if this is confusing, i wasn't sure how to type this equation in here to ask it. If you can please show the steps it would help me because I have a test coming soon. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

$$\log_3(1/3)=\log_33^{-1}=-1$$
Thus,
$$3^{2y}\times 3^{\log_3(1/3)}=3^{2y}\times 3^{-1}=3^{2y-1}=9=3^2\\
\implies 2y-1=2\\
\implies y=\dfrac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: @IlaIsabelle Sure!